# gnuplot coordinating portions of multiple input files into 2 stacked graphs

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying the multiplot function for the first time, and as I read on another question here, replot doesn't seem well suited here, but I don't understand gnuplot well enough to pursue alternatives.

I have two plots with 2 input files each. The first plot requires selecting data differently for each input file (hence replot). I would like to arrange these two plots stacked in 2 rows, 1 column.

If I remove the input for either graph, I can plot them individually just fine, so the syntax is correct at least to that extent.

Here is my input:

```
se te po enh co so
se ou "plot_tfoh-2.ipdip"
set xrange[10:50]
set xlabel "{/ -Bold ionization energy [eV]}"
set ylabel "{/ -Bold spectral intensity}" offset 1.25,0
set tics out
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set title "{/ -Bold tfoh-2 | Ionization Spectra}" offset 0,-0.5
#FIRST GRAPH (top graph in multiplot)
plot 0 notitle
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 25" w i lt 25
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$20*$20+$19*$19+$18*$18+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 24" w i lt 24
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$19*$19+$18*$18+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 23" w i lt 23
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 22" w i lt 22
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F{/Arial \"}_{py} - F{/Arial '}_{py}" w i lt 21
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$18*$18+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F{/Arial \"}_{py} - F{/Arial '}_{pz}" w i lt 20
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 19" w i lt 19
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "(O-F)_p" w i lt 18
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 17" w i lt 17
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "(O-F)_p" w i lt 16
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 15" w i lt 15
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 14" w i lt 14
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 13" w i lt 13
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 12" w i lt 12
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 11" w i lt 11
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "O_{2s}" w i lt 10
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F{/Arial \"}_{2s}" w i lt 9
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "(F{/Arial '} - F{/Arial \"})_{2s}" w i lt 8
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F_{2s}" w i lt 7
# SECOND GRAPH (bottom graph in multiplot)
plot 0 notitle
replot "//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/dip/plot_tfoh-2.dip.input.dat" notitle w i lc rgb 'grey50'
replot "/worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/dip/final.replotConfig.dat" using 1:2 t "O-F 2h states" w i lc rgb "red"
se te po enh co so
set key top right font ",13"
se ou "ref.plot_tfoh-2.ipdip.ps"
replot
```

I would very much appreciate any help on the matter. If I can add any more details, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the multiplot environment before plotting. Based on your example, it would look similar to the following:

```
se te po enh co so
se ou "plot_tfoh-2.ipdip.ps"
set xrange[10:50]
set xlabel "{/ -Bold ionization energy [eV]}"
set ylabel "{/ -Bold spectral intensity}" offset 1.25,0
set tics out
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set title "{/ -Bold tfoh-2 | Ionization Spectra}" offset 0,-0.5

set multiplot layout 2,1

#FIRST GRAPH (top graph in multiplot)
plot 0 notitle,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 25" w i lt 25,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$20*$20+$19*$19+$18*$18+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 24" w i lt 24,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$19*$19+$18*$18+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 23" w i lt 23,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 22" w i lt 22,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F{/Arial \"}_{py} - F{/Arial '}_{py}" w i lt 21,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$18*$18+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F{/Arial \"}_{py} - F{/Arial '}_{pz}" w i lt 20,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 19" w i lt 19,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$17*$17+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "(O-F)_p" w i lt 18,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 17" w i lt 17,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$16*$16+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "(O-F)_p" w i lt 16,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$15*$15+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 15" w i lt 15,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 14" w i lt 14,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$14*$14+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 13" w i lt 13,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$13*$13+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 12" w i lt 12,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$12*$12+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "orb 11" w i lt 11,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$11*$11+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "O_{2s}" w i lt 10,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.2.dat" u 2:(+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F{/Arial \"}_{2s}" w i lt 9,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$10*$10+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "(F{/Arial '} - F{/Arial \"})_{2s}" w i lt 8,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/ip/plot_tfoh-2.ip.1.dat" u 2:(+$9*$9+$8*$8+$7*$7+$6*$6+$5*$5+$4*$4) t "F_{2s}" w i lt 7


# SECOND GRAPH (bottom graph in multiplot)

plot 0 notitle,\
"//worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/dip/plot_tfoh-2.dip.input.dat" notitle w i lc rgb 'grey50',\
"/worka/blaise/masters/results/tfoh-2/dip/final.replotConfig.dat" using 1:2 t "O-F 2h states" w i lc rgb "red"
```

Note that there is no `replot` command, just commas separating the various components of each panel. Please refer to the documentation and [demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/layout.html) for additional examples.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I assume I remove the replot in the final line as well? Do I have to change anything else in the lines following my plot input? When I tried your suggestion, the gnuplot failed to generate.

Comment: Yes, you don't need any `replot` statements in there. Which error did you get?

Comment: I am not seeing any error from gnuplot. I have a .gp file which I run the gnuplot executable on, and the .ps output is generated silently. I have no idea if an error occurred in that step. When I try to open the postscript file via gnu imaging or okular, I simply receive an error that the postscript file could not be opened. Is there a way for me to troubleshoot an error in the gnuplot process? Again, it works when I end the .gp file with replot, just not multiplotted.

Comment: One important thing: on the .gp file you sent, you cannot have the last four lines, because you're setting a new terminal and a new output, which will essentially overwrite the current output.

Comment: I edited my response with your full script. Try to run this and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a ton man. It seems to have worked. That was a huge help. I have to run now, but I assume removing the x-axis label on the top graph and title of second graph is described in the gnuplot documentation?

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, you can always do `unset title` before the second `plot` statement, and that applies also for labels and so on.